# Querying MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query the MySQL database to return some results. For e.g. I have a `HTML` form where user can enter some search values and can execute it. This form contains two fields: `Body` and `Query String` (these are appropriate fields with my database table).

I am executing the query like this:

```
select count(*) from Message;
```

The result is: `7280`

If I execute the query like this:

```
select count(*) from Message where body like '%%';
```

The result is: `7280`

The body does not have any `null` values.

But if I add another empty `like` into the query:

```
select count(*) from Message where body like '%%' and queryString like '%%';
```

There result is: `3353`.

My `queryString` column contains some `null` values, which I am guessing is causing this. What I would like that query to return is the same count of results `(7280)` and ignore those `null` values. How to achieve this using MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `IFNULL` function :

```
select count(*) from Message where body like '%%' and IFNULL(queryString, " ") like '%%';
```

Comment: maybe `IFNULL(queryString, '')` is better.

Comment: Yup, ' ' would also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ((body LIKE '%%') OR (body IS NULL))
and   ((queryString LIKE '%%') OR (queryString IS NULL))
```